# SQL's union default order by clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-order-by, union

I noticed when I am combining two tables via union that the order is not what I expected.

calculus_class

```
Kevin   Le      kevinle892@email.edu
Jackie  Chan    jchan@email.edu
Sam     Smit    ssmitten@email.edu
```

stats_class

```
Kay     Lam     klam204@email.edu
Jackie  Chan    jchan@email.edu
Pooja   Pri     ppriyanka@email.edu
```

When I combine the two tables above

```
select * from calculus_class
union 
select * from stats_class
```

I expect the results to be in order from top to bottom like this:

```
Kevin   Le      kevinle892@email.edu
Jackie  Chan    jchan@email.edu
Sam     Smit    ssmitten@email.edu
Kay     Lam     klam204@email.edu
Jackie  Chan    jchan@email.edu
Pooja   Pri     ppriyanka@email.edu
```

This is the result I received using DBeaver PostgreSQL:

```
Kevin   Le      kevinle892@uci.edu
Pooja   Pri     ppriyanka@uci.edu
Jackie  Chan    jchan473@uci.edu
Sam     Smit    ssmitten@uci.edu
Kay     Lam     klam204@uci.edu
```

Comment: While your question seems to mostly revolve around the use of union vs union all, there is a subtle second effect, which is that there is no basis for the order that you have listed, except maybe "on-disk layout", so the answers below suggesting an order by won't truly reproduce what you listed above. If you think that is important, I'd suggest adding an update statement into the fiddle below before selecting to see this difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you are using `union` which removes duplicates, but you don't want duplicate removal.  So just use `union all`:

```
select * from calculus_class
union all
select * from stats_class;
```

If you did want to order the results, you need to remember that SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.   If you did want the results ordered by something, you could add an `order by`:

```
select * from calculus_class
union all
select * from stats_class
order by fname;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fbdb4d07e99ca03b0608f82ce3cfb97f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to assume that table rows have an inherent ordering. This is not the case. Tables are mode of *unordered sets of rows*, there is no default ordering whatsoever.

Unless you do add an `order by` clause to your query, the ordering in which rows will be returned is undefined: the database is free to return rows in whatever order it likes - this might, or might not, be consistent over consecutive executions of the very same query. Same goes for rows returned by a `union` query (which actually creates a *derived* table).

So, if you want ordering, do use an `order by` clause: it is unclear which column should be used so I put `?` in the query.

```
select *
from (
    select * from calculus_class
    union all
    select * from stats_class
) t
order by  ?
```

If you want rows from the first table first, you can do:

```
select *
from (
    select 1 rn, c.* from calculus_class c
    union all
    select 2 rn, s.* from stats_class
) t
order by  rn
```

Note that I changed `union` to `union all`: unless you do want to eliminate duplicates across the two tables (which is the purpose of `union`), `union all` is more efficient and should always be used.

Answer (score 0):

Nested query is not necessary:

select 1 rn, c.* from calculus_class c
union all
select 2 rn, s.* from stats_class
order by 1